# Moment generating function doubts

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

It´s a continous random variable. I have to get the MGF from a piecewise density function, but then, when I have to get the $\mathbb (x)$, the result is undefined, so I don't know if it's correct or I am doing something incorrectly.

[image: This is the density function]

how can I get the variance knowing that is the mgf second derivate? It is also undefined... when t=0

Comment: In all cases the MGF is
$$\int_0^1 xe^{tx}\,dx+\int_1^2(2-x)e^{tx}\,dx.$$

Comment: But after that, the Expected value its undefined, thats what makes me trouble

Comment: The expectation is $M_X'(0)$ which turns out to be $1$.

Comment: It´s also undefined :C

Comment: I will edit my question and show you my result of my integral

Comment: Why in your new last line are you differentiating with respect to $x$ (a variable that does not occur in your formula)?

Comment: Sorry, it´s d/dt , but happens the same

Comment: Just for those non-spanish speakers out there, *otros casos* can be read as "otherwise"; the exact translation is however "other cases".

Comment: Please consider typesetting with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that the MGF is
$$M_X(t)=\frac{-2e^t+e^{2t}+1}{t^2}.$$
This formula is undefined at $t=0$, but $M_X(0)=1$ (whatever the random variable is).
Then, by definition of derivative,
$$M_X'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{M_X(h)-M_X(0)}{h}
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{M_X(h)-1}{h}
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2e^h+e^{2h}+1-h^2}{h^3}$$
which you can evaluate via the Hospital or via Maclaurin series.

Comment: Thank u so much, just one more quesiton to get the Variance y should do the second derivate and occurs exactly the same, how can I get it?

Comment: can I get it using the limit form  (Mx'(h) - Mx'(0))/h    ?